# CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors not breaking the build

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, code-analysis, csproj

Essentially, I want the build of our system to break when there are any Code Analysis issues.

I have set the following in the `.csproj`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>true</CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But the Code Analysis issues are still not being treated as errors.\

Edit:  I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: which version of visual studio are you using ?

Comment: @dada686: Edited.  Sorry about that!

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce.  Are you sure that you have at least one violation of a rule that is enabled as a warning in the ruleset you are using for the project?

Comment: if you posted more of you proj file it would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to set `RunCodeAnalysis` to true:

```
<PropertyGroup>
     <CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>true</CodeAnalysisTreatWarningsAsErrors>
     <RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Note that RunCodeAnalysis doesn't apply to the Roslyn analyzers, which get activated by having the Nuget package installed.